# change value of attributes of a tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, fieldset

I have the following HTML generated by Drupal

```
<fieldset id="webform-component-lunchset" class="webform-component-fieldset form-wrapper" style="">
    <div id="webform-component-lunchset--lunch" class="form-item webform-component webform-component-radios webform-container-inline" style="">
        ...Radio Button div tags here
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="webform-component-dinnerset" class="webform-component-fieldset form-wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <div id="webform-component-dinnerset--dinner" class="form-item webform-component webform-component-radios webform-container-inline" style="display: none;">
        ...Radio Button div tags here
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

My intent is to allow the user to choose a meal time based on the hour of the day when he initiates a booking. To do this I noticed that I have to change style="display: none;" for the field set I want to hide and style="" for the one I want displayed. I have the following Javascript statements to change the style attribute of the DIV tags but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
window.onload = (function() { 
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var lunchtime1 = document.getElementById('webform-component-lunchset');
    var lunchtime2 = document.getElementById('webform-component-lunchset--lunch');
    var dinnertime1 = document.getElementById('webform-component-dinnerset');
    var dinnertime2 = document.getElementById('webform-component-dinnerset--dinner');
    if (hour >= 15 && hour < 22) {
        lunchtime1.style="display: none;";
        lunchtime2.style="display: none;";
        dinnertime1.style=" ";
        dinnertime2.style=" ";
        sundaytime1.style="display: none;";
    }
});
```

Not sure why it isn't working, would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Give details of Exception or error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use the `style` property of a reference to a node, you're using the DOM API. A DOMElement object has a property, called `style`, which *has* to be an object, too. So either write:

```
lunchtime1.style.display = 'none';
```

Or use the `setAttribute` method - so you can set the entire style attribute in one go:

```
lunchtime1.setAttribute('style','display: block; background-color: #F00;');
```

That should do the trick...

*note:*
As Tim Down pointed out, old IE's don't do `setAttribute` as well as decent browsers, so the first approach is the most reliable. I'm looking into the matter. IE doesn't allow you to write `someNode.setAttribute('onclick', 'clickHandler()');` for example. 
I've also encountered issues that seem to affect only certain elements (often form elements), but when it comes to setting the style attribute, I can't be sure... Either you can't set certain attributes, or you might not be able to set any attribute on some elements. Whatever... I'll update this answer once I know more about this. (currently no windows boxes around, so no IE to test)

Comment: The latter (using `setAttribute()`) will not work in old IE, which has a broken implementation of `setAttribute()`, so the former is better.

Comment: @TimDown: Thanks for the heads-up! I seem to recall that IE8 does support the `setAttribute` method, but now I come to think about it, I seem to recall that some specific nodes were _not_ supported (`<select>` springs to mind, it's always been troublesome in IE). A quick google search tells me that, indeed `setAttribute` doesn't work with event handlers. If you could provide me a link on the subject that is a tab more comprehensive, could you paste it? anyhow, I'll edit my answer

Comment: The issue is that old IE `setAttribute()` attributes maps directly to properties, so trying to set the `style` attribute tries to replace the `style` property, which is not allowed. Here's a reasonable description: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Thank you. Quick responses and a wealth of info. I tried this but seems to have no effect see the HTML and JS http://jsfiddle.net/xR64J/5/

Comment: @sridharpandurangiah: as far as I can tell, it does work, though... perhaps you should clarify what you're expecting to see...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It doesn't seem to change the style attribute. See the HTML and JS -> http://jsfiddle.net/xR64J/8/ Nevertheless let me check it on my site.

Comment: @sridharpandurangiah:The html shown in a fiddle won't change, of course. Also: change the _onLoad_ to _no wrap (head)_ on the left hand side: your handler should be triggered on the load event, but you've set up the fiddle to run after the load event, so your code never gets executed

Comment: Thanks @EliasVanOotegem , it works now.      dinnertime1.style.display="none"; dinnertime2.style.display="block";

Answer (score 0):

```
dinnertime1.style.display="inline";
```

Comment: Sorry, wasn't looking carefully enough :-s

Answer (score 0):

I think `style="<string>"` isn't possible. You have to write `lunchtime1.style.display = "none"`. Style is a "full" js-object.

Anyway, is there a reason not to use jQuery?

Comment: Why should the OP use jQuery? some people just want to learn JavaScript itself... besides, for simple things like this, jQuery is just adding pointless bulk. Setting a style attribute is fairly X-browser, a tad faster and actually requires _less_ code. IMO, less is better, the DOM is slow enough as is

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Why jQuery? I *love* not having to think about browser version/bugs/differences/... more than I still have to - css support and other "different approaches" need my attention. And *even in this simple case you cross these issues* as you noted in your answer. And as of speed ... you're right, but I think *maintenability/compatibility* is easier to achieve with jQuery (views may differ). And if something is ***really* slow** at some part of your page on a certain target device, ***then optimize*** it - otherwise it may lead to premature optimization.

Comment: @Warappa: I am fully aware of the benefits of jQuery, or may be not fully, but I can certainly see a case for it. The main issue I have with jQuery is that people turn to it way to soon. Learn JavaScript, too, and you'll be able to get more out of jQuery, it's JS after all. Even though some people here seem to think of jQuery as a separate language. You talk about optimizing code: optimizing your jQuery code becomes a lot easier when you know your way around the language